# Ignoring certain Label value between lower-upperbound in LineChart via custom code JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, linechart

Background:I have a chart that takes minute data points based on timestamp(X values) from 930am to 4pm every day.Let's say its currently 1 PM Friday; my chart should show all value from thursday 1PM to Friday 1PM which it does but notice on the graph there is big red line drawn from 4pm thursday to Friday 930am since there are no data(and there never will be).

see chart :[image]

Since I have set the X axis lower bound to be 1pm Thursday in timestamp with its upperbound Friday 1pm and tickUnit 2 hours, the axis will create Major label Thursday 1pm,5pm,9pm ; 1am Friday, 5am, 9am,1pm even though there is no need to create label/space from Thursday 4pm to Friday 9am.

Is there a way to tell the X-axis to create ticklabel between Thursday 1pm to Friday 1Pm but ignore certain case or go around this problem in a different way?

I wrote a Sample Test Code that show the issue(with bigger scale):I want to remove the line/tickLabel category space between 17pm and 930am next day as there is no data.

```
public class TestGraph extends Application{
private NumberAxis yQuoteChartAxis;
private NumberAxis xQuoteChartAxis;
private XYChart.Series<Long,Double> series;
private LineChart<Long, Double> qChart;
private final static long TWOHOURS_MILLISECONDS=7200000;
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    xQuoteChartAxis=new NumberAxis();
    yQuoteChartAxis=new NumberAxis();
    yQuoteChartAxis.setSide(Side.RIGHT);
    yQuoteChartAxis.setMinorTickVisible(false);
    xQuoteChartAxis.setMinorTickVisible(false);
    xQuoteChartAxis.setAutoRanging(false);
    series=new XYChart.Series<>();
    qChart=new LineChart(xQuoteChartAxis,yQuoteChartAxis);
    qChart.setCreateSymbols(false);
    qChart.setLegendVisible(false);
    series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<Long,Double>(1467306000000l, 23.0));
    series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<Long,Double>(1467309600000l, 23.05));
    series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<Long,Double>(1467313200000l, 25.14));
    series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<Long,Double>(1467316800000l, 17.5));
    series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<Long,Double>(1467320400000l, 15.00));
    series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<Long,Double>(1467378000000l, 14.0));
    series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<Long,Double>(1467381600000l, 15.0));
    series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<Long,Double>(1467392400000l, 36.0));

    xQuoteChartAxis.setTickLabelFormatter(new NumberAxis.DefaultFormatter(xQuoteChartAxis){
         @Override public String toString(Number object) {
             Long dateLong=object.longValue();
             Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
             cal.setTimeInMillis(dateLong);
             String amOrPm=(cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)>=12 && cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)<24) ? "PM":"AM";
             return String.format("%1$s"+amOrPm, cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)); }
     });
    Scene scene  = new Scene(qChart,800,600);
    qChart.getData().add(series);
    DateFormat df=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    String todayStr="2016-07-01 13:00:00";
    Date today=df.parse(todayStr);
    String yesterdayStr="2016-06-30 13:00:00";
    Date yesterday=df.parse(yesterdayStr);
    System.out.println(today.getTime());
    System.out.println(yesterday.getTime());
    xQuoteChartAxis.setLowerBound(yesterday.getTime());
    xQuoteChartAxis.setUpperBound(today.getTime());
    xQuoteChartAxis.setTickUnit(TWOHOURS_MILLISECONDS);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```

Comment: [Provide the code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for an application which generates the chart you have.  It would be easier for somebody to answer this starting from code that generates your current chart.

Comment: noted, I updated the post.